# Openoffice formula into math.stackexchange post

Tags: support, mathjax

I have a question to ask and can't cut and paste the many formula into this post.

Is there anyway to do it without having to learn MathJaX?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to happen. Do you want to copy formulae from here into OO, or do you want to write formulae here and you just don't know how to $\TeX$?

Comment: @J.M. My assumption would be that OOffice has some kind of GUI for entering formulas, and he would like to copy formulas from there instead of just typing them directly into the question box here.

Comment: I have the formula in OO and want to get it here. OO has a formula gui built into it and writer places it in the document as an object. I don't know tex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenOffice lets you save formulas as MathML, which you could then convert to LaTeX using one of the many [MathML to LaTeX converters](http://www.google.com/search?q=mathml+to+latex) out there. Disclaimer: I haven't tried any of them, so I have no idea if they work.

Sadly, while [MathJax actually does support MathML directly](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/mathml-samples/), this feature isn't enabled in the deployment here on Stack Exchange.